# Existence of centrifugal force in question

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, centrifugal-force

I am new to circular motion.I came across a question which had a car going up the top of the hill in which we were asked about the normal reaction on the car due to its movement along the curved part.

Obviously the car follows circular motion but problem came when I thought of the force due to circular motion-I am still confused why the weight of car should decrease,when we know that centripetal force acts towards the centre. This should have worked and increased the normal.I want to know where i erred in thinking and also want an easy to understand justification of how and why a centrifugal force would act.

Any help to resolve my problem would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a sketch by any chance?

Answer (score 1):

One does not need to introduce the concept of a centrifugal force acting on the car to explain the apparent loss in weight of the car.

If you mean by *weight* the force on a mass due to gravitational attraction then in the example that you have given the weight of the car does not change.
However what I call *apparent weight*, the force that a mass would exert on a force measuring device, eg bathroom scales calibrated in newtons, will change.

Consider a stationary car placed on a large set of bathroom scales.
The two vertical forces acting on the car are its weight, $mg$, which acts downwards and the upward normal force due to the bathroom scales, $N$.
Applying Newton's second law wit down as the positive direction give $mg-N =m\,0 \Rightarrow mg=N$.

In turn the car exerts a normal force on the bathroom scales equal to $N$ but in the downward direction and this is the reading on the bathroom scales $(=mg)$.

Now at the top of the hill suppose that the car moving at a speed $v$ and the road is part of an arc of a vertical circle of radius $R$, ie the car is undergoing circular motion and underneath the car there are bathroom scales.

The equation of motion of the car is now $mg-N'= m\dfrac{v^2}{R}$ where $N'$ is the upward normal force exerted by the bathroom scales on the car.
It is now the case that $N' <mg$
In turn the $N'$ is the magnitude of the downward force exerted on the bathroom scales by the car - the reading on the bathroom scales, the apparent weight of the car, and that reading is less than $mg$ the weight of the car.

An extreme case is when the speed and/or the radius is such that $N'=0$ and the car appears to be weightless as $mg = m \dfrac {v'^2}{R'}$.
Going any faster and the car leaves the road and travels along a trajectory whose radius is less than that of the road.

---

When you introduce a centripetal force it is because you are considering the motion in the reference frame of the car and that reference frame is accelerating relative to the ground.
Now relative to the car the car is not accelerating and yet it has a net force acting on it, $mg-N'$ so Newton's second law is not working!

To overcome this problem a fictitious upward force $m \dfrac {v'^2}{R'}$is introduce (the centrifugal force) to make Newton's second law work, $mg - N'- m\dfrac{v'^2}{R'} = m\, 0$.

Comment: And an observer from ground would see which forces?

Comment: Also would any form of centripetal acceleration work?..as centripetal force exists in any circular motion...why are we ignoring that force?

Comment: There is really no such thing as a centripetal force.  What there is is a  centripetal acceleration which is the result of the net force acting on a body.  So in the first part of my answer the net force which causes the centripetal acceleration $\frac{v'^2}{R}$ is $mg-N'$.

Comment: An observer on the ground "sees" forces $mg$ and $N'$.

Answer (score 1):

Imagine driving so fast over the hill that you leave the ground. So fast that the hill acts as a ramp. When you leave the ground, the normal force is zero since there is nothing for the ground to hold up against.

This is caused by your inertia wanting to continue with the speed you have given it. Gravity pulls downwards, but inertia causes a leap off of the ground for just a short while.

Between your car being on flat ground with full normal force and leaving the ground reaching zero normal force, the normal force will gradually reduce.

**This is why** you get a lower normal force while driving over a hill. Even without leaving the ground, the car still has the tendency due to its inertia to want to leap off of the ground. This releaves for just a moment the load on the ground and thus reduces for just a moment the normal force.

Comment: I got what u meant...but won't there be any acceleration towards the centre of the circle of which the hill is an arc...am i correct in thinking that some centripetal force would work in increasing apparent weight of the car?

Comment: @Mathenthusiast Indeed, but that centripetal acceleration is gravity. It is *already accounted for*. The fact that you have a weight even when standing still is due to gravity. When you move in an arc, gravity is the centripetal acceleration and it is already acting - the only difference is that your direction happens to shape an arc.

Comment: Oh now i get it....i thought there was another force other than gravity as centripetal force...but if there would be another force say acting on the car vertically downwards...then the centripetal would be the resultant of the 2 forces right?

Comment: @Mathenthusiast Yes, if the car was driving in a magnet or so, then that force would have to be added to the already acting gravitational force. And the centripetal force would then be the sum.